# SQL INSERT INTO varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to insert 3 Values in my varchar column K_Name but when I try to insert them with the INSERT INTO command it gives me the following error: [image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a primary key column and need  only an autoincrement the you could try

```
ALTER TABLE tblkunden MODIFY COLUMN K_Nr INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

otherwise you should add the autoincrement clause at you table creation's script

Comment: This doesn't work because K_Nr is used as a forgein key in another table is there a way I can alter an column that is used as a forgein key in another table?

Comment: I managed to change it thank you very much for your help my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you clearly have another column that is a primary key with a default value of `0` or `'0`'.

Your table should probably look like:

```
create table tblkunden (
    kunden_id int auto_increment primary key,
    k_name varchar(<whatever>)
);
```

Then your insert should work.

A primary key should not have a default value.  Simply declaring it as a `primary key` means that it cannot be `null` and that duplicates cannot be inserted.  Declaring it as `auto_increment` ensures that the value is assigned in an `insert`.

Comment: I have structured my table like this already (I think at least) but it still doesn't work for me. It is structured as followed:    `MariaDB [awp]> CREATE TABLE tblkunden(
    -> K_Nr int(11),
    -> K_Name varchar(30),
    -> K_CreditCardNr char(16),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(K_Nr)
    -> );`

Comment: You need to declare it as `auto_increment`, not merely as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
INSERT INTO tblkunden (K_Nr, k_name)
VALUES(1,'Hans'),
(2,'Franz'),
(3, 'Peter');
```

This is because you can not have a NULL within a primary key which is the k_Nr column and because it is a primary key, it needs to be a unique value.

You can also use the primary key as an auto_increment which is mentioned in an answer above, this will increment each value by 1, you can change this to have a different increment if needed.

I hope this makes sense.